# Updating Pgadmin4 from 3.4 to 4.2

Tags: pgadmin

I have installed pgadmin4 and i can access it from browser everything is okay but it is showing a popup that the version is 3.4 and latest version is 4.2.I have to update it from 3.4 version to 4.2,how to update it as there are docs only on installing pgadmin not on updating pgadmin.

Answer (score 1):

In order to upgrade do the following:

```
virtualenv -p python3 pgadmin4 

cd pgadmin4 

source bin/activate 

pip3 install https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.3/pip/pgadmin4-4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

In some cases it changes the http://12.70.0.1:[port] to http://localhost:[port]

to fix this edit the pgAdmin4/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py (or the version you actually have if it's different) file by updating the line:

```
 DEFAULT_SERVER = '127.0.0.1'
```

to:

```
 DEFAULT_SERVER = 'localhost'
```